# C - Best way to read file line by line

Tags: c

fist post on Stack Overflow. 
If you have to read from a file structured composed by a line with a name and then 15 lines of numbers, so the file look like:

```
NAME1
NUM1
NUM2
...
...
...
NUM15
```

also you don't know how many lines has the file (but they obviously will be a multiple of 16), what is the simplest way to read every line and put it in a structure like:

```
struct something {
        char name[128];
         int nums[15]:
}
```

?

I used a while(fgets) to read every line until EOF and sscanf to analyze every line and put it in the structure, but i had some difficulties like doubled or causual numbers.
Edit: i can't post the code because i wrote it on University PC, so i can't access here right now

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also recommend you read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons you will be getting negative votes for this question.

Comment: _I had some difficulties like doubled or causual numbers_: maybe you should tell us more about these difficultiues. It's hard to guess what difficulties you have. Please [edit]  your question. Don't describe your code, but show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)(pFile, "%s %d %d %d (15times %d for 15 integers, other datatypes require different %...)", name, num1, num2, ....);

at some point fscanf will fail, you should be able to retrieve a EOF then (either using a different fscanf, fgets or whatever)